# ION-LIST fill left an right side with different contents

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, fill, ion-list

I want to fill the left side and the right side of an ion-list with different Weatherdata of different countries. I hope someone can help me. I have been looking for a solution for hours.

[CLICK HERE FOR THE GUI OF THE APPLICATION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wy1ew.png)

[THIS IS THE GUI OF THE GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAdZn.png)

This is how my code looks like for the selection of the ion-list:

```
<ion-view title="Termine" hide-nav-bar="true" id="page3" style="background-color: rgb(220, 220, 224);" >
  <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
      <button class="button button-icon icon ion-plus-round"></button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>
  <ion-content padding="true" class="manual-ios-statusbar-padding">

    <div ng-controller="WeatherBerlinCtrl">
    <!-- WEATHER SECTION -->
    <ion-list id="termine-list">
      <ion-item class="item-thumbnail-left" id="termine-list-item46"style="">

      <img src={{vWeatherLinkIcon}}>
      <h2 style="text-align: left; width:49%; display: inline-block; font-weight: bold;">Berlin {{vWeatherActDegrees}} °C</h2> 

      <!-- <img style="float: right;" src={{vWeatherLinkIcon}}> -->
      <h2>Max: {{vWeatherMaxDegrees}} °C</h2>
      <h2>Min: {{vWeatherMinDegrees}} °C</h2>

<!--       <div class="item-thumbnail-right">
                <img style="float: right;"  src={{vWeatherLinkIcon}}>
     <div ng-controller="WeatherKabulCtrl">
      <h2 style="text-align: right; width:50%;  display: inline-block;  font-weight: bold;">Berlin {{vWeatherActDegrees}} °C</h2>
                      </div> -->

    </ion-list>
    <div class="spacer" style="width: 748px; height: 15px;"></div>`
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using an ion-grid inside your ion-list ?

```
 <ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
      left
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      right
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

[ionic doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/grid/Grid/)